# Ember.js v1.2.0 - Ember.Component not firing 'click' handler, returning null for this.$()

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using `Ember v1.2.0` along with `Handlebars v1.0.0` and `jQuery v2.0.2` and I started to use `Ember.Component` and replace some views I created through components (for example a custom dropdown element) and it felt like the right thing to do, but unfortunately it does not work as I expected.

this is my `Handlebars` file, placed under `templates/components/my-dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown__header" {{action 'toggle'}}>
    <i {{bind-attr class=view.iconClass}}></i>{{view.displayText}}
</div>
<div class="dropdown__caret"></div>
<ul class="dropdown__body">
  {{yield}}
</ul>
```

this is the corresponding `Ember.Component` class:

```
App.MyDropdownComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: 'dropdown'.w(),

  toggleList: function () {
    //var $this = this.$(); // returns null (!!!)
    var $this = this.$('.' + this.get('classNames').join(' .')); // returns the expected object
    if($this.hasClass('open')) {
      $this.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      $this.addClass('open');
    }
    // Note: I can't work with classNameBindings and toggleProperty() because the classes
    // could also be accessed through other code...
  },

  click: function (event) {
    alert('heureka!'); // never fired!
  },

  actions: {
    toggle: function () {
      this.toggleList(); // fired as expected
    }
  }
});
```

is this **expected behaviour** of an `Ember.Component`?

Comment: Your component name doesn't match with the template, you need to change to `App.MyDropdownComponent`.

Comment: Thanks @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior - I just wrote the code here from the top of my head and didn't realize I used a wrong name... I'll updating the thread so that it fits the naming convention. Nevertheless, the behaviour is still the same... :(

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ObuciYO/1/edit , can you show us how you're using it?  It looks like it's functioning properly in the jsbin.